# $PATH error every time Terminal is Opened

Tags: bash, macos, .profile

I had installed **Postgres.app** before and after I uninstalled via [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) now every time I open terminal this error appears in the first line I should mention that a followed what documentation for uninstalling the Postgres on their website but it doesn't work for me.

```
Warning: $PATH entry "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin" is not valid (No such file or directory)
```

**.bash_profile:**

```
# source ~/.profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@6/bin:$PATH"
```

how can I get rid of this annoying warning?
Thanks.

Comment: The problematic PATH entry is not added in your `.bash_profile`. To remove it you have to find the file in which it is added. Could it be part of `.profile`?

Comment: or `.bash_rc` perhaps if you have one

Answer (score 0):

You should look at all bash initialization files. There may be many, depending on your distro. There's a good list on [tldp](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html):

- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/bashrc`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`

Consider that some of these files may also include all files in some directory. For example on most instances `/etc/profile` will run every .sh file in `/etc/profile.d/`, this may include a paths file called `/etc/profile.d/extrapaths.sh`.

EDIT:

After checking the documentation for PostgresApp ([1](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/blob/841973652fed0752641e899331b4402a834b214e/docs/documentation/cli-tools.md), [2](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/blob/841973652fed0752641e899331b4402a834b214e/docs/documentation/install.md#uninstalling-postgresapp)), and this [issue](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/259) I found that it uses a file called `/etc/paths.d/postgresapp`. Be sure to check it.

If you'd like to remove the paths, it states that you should run the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```